# Redistribution of histogram type data in specified bins with Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution, binning

In Matlab, I am trying to redistribute data with a step of 4 into a new binning of step 3, as pictured below with input X = [4,16,8] and desired output Y = [3,9,10,6]. What is the most efficient way to do so? Random drawings take too long for my current needs.

[image]

Comment: I assume you want this distributed with area? The real error-free way of doing this is making another histogram from the data, otherwise you will be introducing more error.

Comment: Yes. What is the fastest way to do so? Until now I have been re-creating data from the first histogram by randomly drawing values in each bin, then redistributing them in the new bins, but a large number of drawings is needed for accuracy and it takes a long time.

Comment: The fastest way of doing it is computing those areas. The area of B' is the sum of the area of A falling on that bin +the area of B on that bin. Should be fairly easy to compute the location of those dashed lines and thus make a tiny script to add those chopped rectangles together.

Comment: Or, depends on what you want, you can also just linearly interpolate.

Comment: OK, I was hoping for a built in function to do it. I will write it then. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Yeah, linear interpolation is a builtin!